# Get synchronously small amount of data from URL

Tags: java, android, ios, kotlin, url

So I have urls with just small icon on them, few kb each and one per url. So basically what I was trying to achieve is to get the icon from `URL`, but not to push this operation to background thread, instead I tried to get it synchronously.

Something similar is possible on iOS for example `NSData` provides that:

```
init(contentsOf url: URL, 
options readOptionsMask: NSData.ReadingOptions = []) throws
```

> Use this method to convert data:// URLs to NSData objects. You can
> also use it to read short files synchronously.

So my thoughts were to read content of URL as bytes. Everything I have found so far about this and `URL`, for Android, is based on `openConnection()` and `getInputStream()` methods. It is well known that Android will not allow this on MainThread. So my question is:

**Is there a way, like on iOS, to get small amount of data from URL synchronously and without moving on background thread?**

Comment: Yes, if you are using OkHttp then `execute()` will run blocking request, and if you are using any Coroutine based library then you can always wrap call under `runBlocking {}`.

Comment: But even if the file is so small, you should never block the main thread, because it is responsible for the responsiveness of the app. If the user is using a really slow network like 1Kbps then what, wouldn't your app be laggy? You should always dispatch IO to Background thread.